# how to detect mobile view and mobile application view in react js

Tags: reactjs

Hello i have developed my website in the react js. I have created ios and android application in that i am using my developed website using url, can any one tell me how to detect mobile  browser view and mobile application view in react js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: You could use the react-device-detect npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect

Comment: i do not want detect mobile browser....i want to detect mobile application

Comment: So you want to know if your website has been opened inside your webview in your app or directly in some browser right ?

Comment: yeah just like that....

Comment: @ManoharPamishetty, Even I am looking for the same solution. You got any info to solve this problem